# Alternative exercise to "Cuff dribbles"

Tags: shoulders, safety

I have just read an article in bodybuilding.com about a *balanced* shoulder workout to build shoulder muscles in a healthy and safe way. Here is the link: http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/the-science-of-shoulder-training-shoulder-workouts.html

The workout consists of four exercises,

1. Shoulder press
2. Bend over laterals
3. [Cuff Dribbles](http://www.coreperformance.com/knowledge/movements/dribble-medicine-ball-rotator-cuff.html)
4. PNF D2 Flexion

Now I want to try this workout (at home) to get a balanced, healty program, but I don't have a medicine ball, and even if I had one I cannot dribble it against the wall. So what are alternatives for the Cuff dribbler exercise in this workout to get a similar balanced shoulder workout? The exercise can use dumbbells or resistance bands as equipment.

Answer (score 1):

I would do internal and external rotation exercises with a resistance band.

For internal - Fix a band around a fixed point.  Start side on to band. With arm closest to band, fix elbow into waist.  Take hand/forearm across body and back, keeping elbow at 90 degrees.

External rotation - again fix band. With arm furtherest from band.  Start with elbow fixed to waist and across stomach.  Stretch resistant band, keeping elbow at 90 degrees and into elbow.

There is a YouTube example here. I have only watched first 2 exercises mentioned here, so can't comment on the rest of the clip.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EY2tNBOmvGs&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Answer (score 0):

P90X and Insanity both have some moves for working the shoulder muscles. I don't know the names but I can describe the moves. They can be completed without any additional weight *(add weights at your own risk)*.

#### Exercise 1

You spread your arms in a wing-like position. You then rotate the shoulders forward for about 30 seconds; repeat the rotation in a backward movement. You then repeat the forward motion while increasing the diameter of the rotation. Repeat  the same using the backward rotation.

#### Exercise 2

From the wing-like position in Exercise 1, bring your arms together so that they clap each other above your head. Then, return to the initial position. Repeat for about a minute. Then, from the initial position, bring the arms together in front of your chest. Then, return to the initial position. Repeat for about 30 seconds.

#### Exercise 3

This works both the shoulders and thighs. Hold an imaginary basketball. Squat for a second and then jump as if you're shooting the ball into a net. Your arms should be extended when throwing the ball *(if the movement is confusing, watch a basketball game on Youtube)*. 
 
There are probably other shoulder exercises out there, but those are the main ones I know and use *(apart from body-weight exercises)*.